# ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize return null after rework on the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serialization, protocol-buffers

I am using visual studio 2010, working on the website project with c#.  When I first save the file with ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize and reopen it many times, it works.  However, when I close the project and reopen the website project again,
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize return null.  I run the md5sum on the saved file, the checksum is still the same.  I need help. Below is the code

Thanks,
Jason

```
 public class jIO
{
    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    //public j_TableRow[] tbl { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> items { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
    public Dictionary<string, Byte[]> images { get; set; }

    public static MemoryStream Serialize(jIO tData)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, tData);
            //Int64 size = ms.Length;
            return ms;
        }
    }
    public static void Serialize(jIO tData, string path)
    {
        //using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(fs, tData);
        }
    }
    public static jIO Deserialize(string path)
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<jIO>(fs);
        }
    }
    public static jIO Deserialize(byte[] tData)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(tData))
        {
            return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<jIO>(ms);
        }
    }
}
```